# Angular 16 - Module build failed

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

After updating angular cli to version 16 and node to version 18, and then creating a new blank angular application via cli. When a try to start the application I'm getting the following

```
Build at: 2023-07-06T12:35:43.339Z - Hash: 4b410e02e402e311 - Time: 3150ms

./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/common.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: C:\Users\Bruno Ferreira\Desktop\Repos\fds\node_modules\@angular\common\fesm2022\common.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')

./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2022/platform-browser.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: C:\Users\Bruno Ferreira\Desktop\Repos\fds\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\fesm2022\platform-browser.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')

./node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2022/router.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: C:\Users\Bruno Ferreira\Desktop\Repos\fds\node_modules\@angular\router\fesm2022\router.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')
```

I have tried to uninstall globally angular cli and then reinstall it. I also deleted node_modules locally. I deleted package-lock.json. I confirmed that the version I'm using are compatible: https://angular.io/guide/versions

I really don't see why I'm having this kind of error in a blank app

Comment: Indeed it worked. How have I missed that answer... my bad! Thank you for your help mate. Cheers.